# MVC Markup Navigate to CSS Class (F12)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In ASP.Net Markup, I can press F12 on a CssClass, and Visual Studio will navigate to the class on the CSS file.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblError" CssClass="errorLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

In MVC Markup, This functionality does not seems exist.

```
<div class="errorLabel"><p>Error</p></div>
```

I assume this doesn't work by design, but does anyone know if it can be enabled?

Comment: it should work according to http://ppe.blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/12/24/go-to-definition-for-css-vstipfind0021.aspx
What version of VS are you using?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know that but I would strongly suggest Resharper which does what you want and a lot more, including javascript gotos.